# A scheme simple over Spec(A)?

Tags: definitions, ag.algebraic-geometry

What does it mean to say that a scheme $X$ is **simple** over $Spec(A)$ ?

I stumbled on this terminology in a paper of S. Lubkin entitled "On a conjecture of Andre Weil".

Comment: "Simple" means "smooth" in this context.

Comment: From the Introduction in SGA1: "/.../ et de faire un ajustage terminologique, le mot \og morphisme simple\fg ayant notamment \'et\'e remplac\'e entre-temps par celui de \og morphisme lisse\fg, qui ne pr\^ete pas aux m\^emes confusions."

Comment: Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: This question just floated back to the surface; it would be good if somebody wrote up A Stasinski's comment as an answer, to stop that happening repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copied A. Stasinsky's comment who quoted a passage in the introduction of SGA1:

"/.../ et de faire un ajustage terminologique, le mot **morphisme simple** ayant notamment \'et\'e remplac\'e entre-temps par celui de **morphisme lisse**, qui ne pr\^ete pas aux m\^emes confusions."

Answer (score -1):

Because a scheme is a locally ringed space X, then it is simple if its topology does not contain a nontrivial two sided ideal. As Spec(A) is referring to the spectrum, this scheme is simple if the set of all proper prime ideals of the noncommutative ring A does not contain any nontrivial two sided ideals defined by x $\cdot$ r $\in$ I, r $\cdot$ x $\in$ I, if the set of ideals (I,+) is a subgroup of an additive group (R,+). In a commutative ring, this is true for all ideals in I.

Comment: As explained in the above comments, "simple" meant something else in this context. This other usage is, however, largely obsolete.

Comment: I meant "simple=smooth" is obsolete.